# Select options from a file

Tags: html, jquery, select

I have this requirement to load select options from a file(for country list). I am able to do that fine, but the state list is on another dependent file, I am able to load that on change of countries as well:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="country" class="form-control1">Country:</label>
<select class="form-cont-reqd" id="country" name="country" placeholder="country">
  <option>Select</option>
</select><br>
<label for="state" class="form-control1">State:</label>
<select class="form-cont-reqd" id="state" name="state" placeholder="state">
  <option>Select Country first</option>
</select><br>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#country").load("options/countries.txt");
  $("#country").change(function() {
    $("#state").load("options/" + $(this).val() + ".txt");
  });
});
</script>
```

Here is the issue. When the user selects it first time, I save it to database. However when the user comes back to the form for modification of the data, Country select loads but state doesnt load because it is dependent on click event of the country.
Can anyone suggest a method/event by which I can accomplish this? I am stumped so far.
Thx

Comment: Are you moving from one page to another and back when you say "However when the user comes back to the form for modification of the data"?

Comment: Thats correct, When user moves from page to page, and comes back to this page then the select option for state is not populated automatically.

Comment: is there a country selected by default?

Comment: I can select USA by default. right now no.

Answer (score 1):

After loading the country menu, trigger the `change` event on it to load the state menu.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#country").load("options/countries.txt", function() {
    $(this).change();
  });
  $("#country").change(function() {
    $("#state").load("options/" + $(this).val() + ".txt");
  });
});
```